# Could not load file or assembly 'Moq, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have added unit test project where I have added Nunit and moq  while running unit test it's throwing exception.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Moq, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Where should I be looking at to resolve this exception?

Comment: If you open the Moq.dll in ildasm, what version are you looking at? In your project file, which version is referenced there? Make sure they match.

Comment: I do not  know how o check ildsam , Is there any other solution I can fix this. please help.